# Why Particplesystem Position is wrong while attached to a GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working with unity 5(2D project).
I attached a ParticleSystem to a GameObject(an UI Button). now i can see both of them but they are not in the same position.
I move particplesystem manually and put both object in the same position .but when i move my object they will not move togothere... particlesystem will move lower and objects will have different positions.

[image: attache particlesystem to ui button]
[image: put manually in the same position]
[image: move button manually but not same position]

Comment: Keep in mind, that there is screen space and world space GUI.

Comment: if Code Clown is right and you are using a screen space GUI you will need to add a script to your particle system which transforms the GUI's screen position to world position and then to the particle system's local position in each update. Don't forget to also exec this in the editor using a class attribute.

Comment: yes i'm using "screen space overlay" in canvas. can you tell me how to convert GUI's screen position to world position and then to the particle system's local position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you from  @Code Clown and  @Noel Widmer. 
as my friends said at first i should transforms the GUI's screen position to world position and then to the particle system's local position in each update.

I made this by these two line of codes.

```
Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(GameObject.Find("MyObject").transform.position);
transform.localPosition = p;
```